# Fragment does not create its corresponding view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I have a TabLayout with 2 tabs. For each tab, I created the corresponding fragments.

The activity class (extending AppCompatActivity) is this (ToolsActivity.java):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tools);
    SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
    TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    tabs.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_reading);
    tabs.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_writing);

    tabs.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);

    mCurrentSelectedListener = new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            // ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            // ...
        }
    };

    tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(mCurrentSelectedListener);
}
```

The corresponding layout is this (activity_tools.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ToolsActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
            android:padding="@dimen/appbar_padding"
            android:text="@string/title_activity_tools"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:tabInlineLabel="true" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The pager adapter contains an array of Fragment object.

```
    mLstFragments.add(new UHFReadFragment());
    mLstFragments.add(new UHFWriteFragment());
```

that adapter also contains this piece of code:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if (mLstFragments.size() > 0) {
        return mLstFragments.get(position);
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException("No fragment at position " + position);
}
```

First tab is UHFReadFragment. This is part of the code of it:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    mContext = (ToolsActivity) getActivity();
    mSound = new Sound(mContext);

    mTagList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    mAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(mContext, mTagList, R.layout.listtag_items,
            new String[]{"tagUii", "tagLen", "tagCount", "tagRssi"},
            new int[]{R.id.TvTagUii, R.id.TvTagLen, R.id.TvTagCount,
                    R.id.TvTagRssi});

    mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            String result = msg.obj + "";
            String[] strs = result.split("@");
            addEPCToList(strs[0], strs[1]);
            mSound.playSound(1);
        }
    };

    mUHF = new UHF(mContext, mHandler);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    mTvCount = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tv_count);
    mLvTags = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.LvTags);
    mLvTags.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

And finally, this is the layout for the first fragment (uhf_read_fragment.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.main.UHFReadFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/tvTagUii"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_count"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@color/red"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/tvTagLen"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/tvTagCount"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="RSSI"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:background="@color/gray" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/LvTags"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that the layout of the fragments does not appear, and in fact, onViewCreated is never called.

What else is missing? I thought that by using "tools:context=".ui.main.UHFReadFragment"" the layout will be associated to the class that controls the Fragment.

Only the layout of the activity is shown (when running the app, it shows only the title and the tabs  header).

Regards
Jaime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the `onCreateView` method in the Fragment class(UHFReadFragment) to inflate the layout

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // Inflate the layout for this fragment
  return inflater.inflate(R.layout.uhf_read_fragment, container, false);
}
```

Hope this will solve your issue